# Having audio sync issues after concatenating several mp4 with and without sound

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm posting today because I have a problem when I use ffmpeg. I have a small program that creates mp4 files for me, often with sounds and sometimes without, until now I used ffmpeg to concatenate them.

But I just realized that if I have an mp4 file that doesn't contain audio then the whole audio track of the final file **goes out of sync**. This only happens when I have some mp4 files that don't have audio. I think it's also useful to know that the program I'm using gives me a lot of mp4 (>20) and **I can't know in advance which ones have audio or not...**

Here is the code I use, I saw on the forum that the mp4 format was badly managed and that it was better to use ts format for concatenation that's why I do this

```
for f in $(ls *.mp4); do
   ffmpeg -i $f -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts $f.ts
done

CONCAT=$(echo $(ls *.ts ) | sed -e "s/ /|/g")

ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i "concat:$CONCAT" -c copy output.ts
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i output.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

I noticed that when the final file goes out of sync this error appears :

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'concat:video0.mp4.ts|video01.mp4.ts|video012.mp4.ts|video0123.mp4.ts|video01234.mp4.ts|video012345.mp4.ts|video0123456.mp4.ts|video01234567.mp4.ts|video012345678.mp4.ts|video0123456789.mp4.ts|video012345678910.mp4.ts|video01234567891011.mp4.ts|video0123456789101112.mp4.ts|video012345678910111213.mp4.ts|video01234567891011121314.mp4.ts|video0123456789101112131415.mp4.ts|video012345678910111213141516.mp4.ts|video01234567891011121314151617.mp4.ts|video0123456789101112131415161718.mp4.ts|video012345678910111213141516171819.mp4.ts|zzzz.mp4.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 1.420222, bitrate: 63089 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x1136, 30 fps, 240 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 145 kb/s
Output #0, mpegts, to 'output.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x1136, q=2-31, 30 fps, 240 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 145 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x7f9c68800000] DTS 130180 < 573000 out of order <-- HERE
[mpegts @ 0x7f9c68800000] DTS 130180 < 654000 out of order <-- HERE
[mpegts @ 0x7f9c68800000] DTS 130180 < 1477180 out of order <-- HERE
```

I've tried several different combinations of members answer on other topics but nothing worked for me.
I don't know if the problem comes from the moment I convert .mp4 files to .ts and I forget to set appropriate codec, or if it comes from the concat command ?

I'm almost sure that there is a simple way to fix this issue but unfortunately I don't have enough ffmpeg knowledge.

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT 1 :**

I changed the for loop of the programme to :

```
for f in $(ls *.mp4); do

    TEST=$(ffprobe -i $f -show_streams -select_streams a -loglevel error)

    if [ "$TEST" ]; then

        ffmpeg -i $f -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts $f.ts

    fi

done
```

It only makes the script to ignore the files that don't have audio, but this way it works, so maybe adding dummy audio to those files could make the job as @Gyan suggested in the comments, but how to do that ?

**EDIT 2 SOLVED**

I found how to add dummy audio on my silent file, that solved my problem this is my final working for loop :

```
for f in $(ls *.mp4); do

    TEST=$(ffprobe -i $f -show_streams -select_streams a -loglevel error)

    if [ "$TEST" ]; then

        ffmpeg -i $f -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts $f.ts

    else

        ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i $f -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:a -map 1:v $f.a.ts
        ffmpeg -i $f.a.ts -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts $f.ts
        rm $f.a.ts

    fi

done
```

Comment: In the files that do have audio, are stream properties identical (codec, channels, frequency..etc). If yes, then adding a dummy audio to those inputs without audio will be the quickest way forward.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I think yes as they come from the same source, only the durations of the videos are different. But how can I add a dummy audio to those files which would fit the duration of the video ?